# Unable to install service worker on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to install a service worker on Safari on iOS 12.1:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
    alert('Success');
} else {
    alert('Fail');
}
```

But instead of seeing `Success`, I get `Fail`.

When trying to register the service worker without checking for support:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
```

The browser simply stops JavaScript execution. I've tested the service worker on Firefox on desktop, and everything works fine.

Am I doing something wrong? According to [Is service worker ready?](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/), Safari on iOS supports service workers. Further, in Safari settings I have `Service Workers` enabled within experimental features. How can I use service workers on iOS?

Comment: Are you testing this on a HTTPS enabled server? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

Comment: @dotconnor Ah, that's the problem. I completely overlooked this since I was testing from localhost on my desktop. Thanks for pointing that out! Is there any way to test without HTTPS?

Comment: No, there is not but you can always run a https server with a self signed certificate and trust it in iOS